# What causes this memory location to be corrupted in some cases and not others?

Tags: c, memory, file-io

When I run the following code with a struct containing a name of hello and the date of today date:

```
typedef struct savedSite{
    char *siteName; 
    char *date; 
} SAVED_SITE;

void printSite(struct savedSite site){
    printf("Site: %s\nDate Added: %s\n",site.siteName,site.date);
    FILE *fpointer;
    fpointer = fopen("storage.txt","a");
    fprintf(fpointer,"Site: %s\nDate Added: %s\n",site.siteName,site.date);
    fclose(fpointer);
}

SAVED_SITE* makeNewSite(){
    SAVED_SITE* returnSite = malloc(sizeof(SAVED_SITE));
    returnSite->siteName = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    returnSite->date = malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
    printf("Enter Site Name: ");
    scanf("%20s", returnSite->siteName);
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[64];
    strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%c", tm);
    returnSite->date = s;
    return returnSite; 
}

int main() {   
    SAVED_SITE *newSite = makeNewSite();    
    printSite(*newSite);
    free (newSite);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a console output of:

```
Site: hello
Date Added: Sat Mar 18 16:37:12 2017
```

but a file output of something like this (Which I assume means that there is a problem in memory, where something that is not a char is being read as a char):

```
Site:n
Date Added: 0í
```

I have tested whether it is because of memory overflow, but when I add further printf's after the first one, they behave as expected, unlike the fprintf. Why is this and how can I write to the file what it had in the console?

(I fixed this question from a previous one that was cancelled because I didn't have enough information. If this one doesn't have enough information, or if it was the wrong practice to re-ask a similar question, let me know. I am fairly new to programming and stack overflow, so advice in general is appreciated. Thanks!)

Comment: `returnSite->date = s;` --> `strcpy(returnSite->date, s);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makeNewSite()` does `returnSite->date = s` where `s` is an array that is local to the function, and ceases to exist when the function returns.   Any usage of the `date` member after the function returns gives undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour means that the C standard does not set limits on what can happen.   One possibility is seeming to work.  Another possibility is behaving in a way that makes you think "problem in memory".     Yet another possibility is that the symptoms you get vary over time, as you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!